# Sub domain redirect (htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, vbulletin

There is soooo much information about htaccess redirect that I think I'm lost.
Here is my current structure

- /web/
- /web/CMS/

In the root I have a vBulletin forum and in /CMS/ I have wordpress. (Ideally I should have vBulletin in a /FORUM/ folder maybe?)

I'd like to setup something like this:

www.domain.com OR domain.com goes to /web/CMS/

forum.domain.com OR forums.domain.com goes to /web/

Then any other subdomain goes to /web/CMS/ (as I'll be using the multi site network of Wordpress)

I have 2 questions:

1. What would be the best structure for this? Maybe I should have my CMS as root and my forum in a folder?
2. How can I do an htaccess that does the job? (do I also need one in /web/CMS/?)

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have vBulletin in your root and you want it to go to forums, you should consider moving it into it's own directory called /forums. Inside the /forums directory, you'll have a .htaccess file generated by vBulletin.

You can keep your WordPress inside /CMS. WordPress will and should have its own htaccess file.

Now if you want to set a subdomain, you'll have to look into your DNS settings and at a minimum setup an A record. If you're on cPanel, this is pretty simple to do inside your DNS Zone section.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that makes sense. I'll do it this way (I use ISP instead of cPanel but it seems fairly simple to configure DNS with too)